# Help using Strcmp() with a binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, strcmp

I have a function   `void display_a_student()` which uses two binary files. Firstly a binary1.dat and and index.dat which contains the offset of each student added to the binary1.dat.

I  am trying to use the index to find the offset value for a student which is entered by the user, I am having trouble using the strcmp() function to compare the value entered to those values held in the index.dat file.

Any help would be much appreciated here is the  code so far.

```
void display_a_student()
{
        struct student aStudent;

        char studentNumSearch[11];
        int index=0;
        int found = false;

        fp = fopen("binary1.dat", "a+b");
        fp1 = fopen("index.dat", "a+b");

        printf("\n\nWhich student are you searching for?");
        scanf("%s", studentNumSearch);
        fflush(stdin);

    while(!found && index < 10)
    {
        if(strcmp(studentNumSearch,fp1[index].studentNum)==0)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        fseek(fp, fp1[index].offset, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&aStudent,sizeof(struct student),1,fp);
        printf("\n\nThe student name is %s\n",aStudent.firstName);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nNo such student\n");

    }

    fclose( fp ); /* fclose closes file */
    fclose (fp1);
    getchar();

}
```

I am certain the line: if(strcmp(studentNumSearch,fp1[index].studentNum)==0)
is where i am going wrong as i am unsure how to point to the file while using the strcmp() function.
- edited code for relevance.

Comment: AFAIK fflush(stdin) is non-standard. Some compilers support it, but fflush(stdout) is the call of that function supported by the standard.  You probably have to flush the input buffer yourself.

Comment: I formatted your code - please use the format button in the editor, or indent all of your code by 4 spaces next time. Also, I would recommend stripping down your sample code to the shortest possible snippet which still contains the relevant lines or demonstrates your problem. The longer your code, the less people take the time to actually read it.

Comment: Please tell us (1) what you expected your code to do, (2) what it actually did, and (3) why you thought it should do #1 instead of #2. Oh, and (4) why you believe the problem is with the line you mention and more specifically with `strcmp`.

Comment: Fp1 is not strictly an array, it's a file pointer (towards the end of your code)

Comment: Have you verified that the `studentNumSearch` and `studentNum` from the binary file are NULL-terminated? Otherwise strcmp will continue to compare characters until it differs (which most likely it will in the binary file). You can also use `strncmp`if you know the length.

Comment: 1: the code is supposed to ask the user for input of a student they wish to search for using their studentNum. Then it uses the index.dat file to find the offset (position) of the student in the binary1.dat and then prints from the binary1.dat position to the screen.

2:It will not compile as it seems i am not using the strcmp() function properly with regards to pointing to the index file correctly for the comparison.

Comment: You have a radical wrong view of FILE pointers. You access it in the strcmp as array (and you try to access a field element called studentNum. That will never pass c-compiler? I recommend you a book/chapter/webpage/man-page about file I/O esp. about fopen, fread, fwrite, fscanf,fprintf, fclose. And if then there are still problems with the strcmp it is maybe, because your data contains 0, so you have, as Benoit already pointed out in his answer, to use memcmp instead.

Answer (score 6):

`strcmp` is for string comparison. Use `memcmp` for binary comparison.

The main issue is your access to `fp1[index]`. This won't work as you access a FILE element never allocated. fp1 is not an array, but a FILE pointer.

You need to use `fscanf` or `fread` to read from the file and `fseek` to position correctly in the file based on index and size of each entry.

Comment: But i am comparing a string that is entered by the user to one thats held in the index.dat structure? Would memcmp still work in this case?

Comment: @James, are you sure these are really strings? Are they null terminated in binary.dat? Anyway, memcmp will work in all cases if you know the length to compare.

Comment: I'm sorry im pretty novice at programming, The 'string' is contained in a structure which was printed to both binary files in another function, I'm unsure what you mean by null terminated sorry =/

Answer (score -1):

I dont think u should use strcmp, you have to use fread to copy into a structure and then use strcmp of what ever you want. 
If you have to use the way u did.. u have use memcmp instead of strcmp, but as Benoit said u need to know the length before u do a cmp.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.